# How can I amend my readAndCast template to cater for my enum class type?

Tags: templates, visual-c++, enums, mfc

I have this existing function:

```
// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58746336/2287576
template <typename T, typename U>
T readAndCast(CArchive& ar) {
    U x;
    ar >> x;
    return static_cast<T> (x);
}
```

It works fine for code like:

```
m_iReminderUnitType = readAndCast<int, DWORD>(ar);
```

Where `m_iReminderUnitType` is of type `int`.

Today I added a new `enum class` to my project:

```
enum class VideoConferenceEventType
{
    Recorded,
    Live
};
```

And I have a variable of that type and I tried to read it in a similar way:

```
m_eVideoconfType = readAndCast(VideoConferenceEventType, DWORD > (ar);
```

It won't work and says *the type name is not allowed*. This surprised me because in reality this `enum class` is an `int.`. How do I fix this?

At the moment I am doing it manually:

```
if (m_dwVersion >= MSA_VERSION_210061)
{
    DWORD dwData;
    ar >> dwData;
    m_eVideoconfType = static_cast<VideoConferenceEventType>(dwData);
    //m_eVideoconfType = readAndCast(VideoConferenceEventType, DWORD > (ar);
}
```

I would prefer to use my `readAndCast` method.

Comment: `m_eVideoconfType = readAndCast(VideoConferenceEventType, DWORD > (ar);` isn't valid C++. There's a closing `)` missing. Did you mean to write `<` in place of the opening `(`?

Comment: @IInspectable Doh! That was it. Thank you.