# Unable to compile this code where my structure uses operator>> overload

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, operator-overloading, structure

I have this structure:

```
struct S_SPECIAL_EVENT
{
    BOOL            bEventAllDay{};

    friend CArchive& operator<<(CArchive& rArchive, S_SPECIAL_EVENT const& rsSE)
    {
        const WORD wVersion = 1;
        return rArchive << wVersion
            << gsl::narrow<bool>(rsSE.bEventAllDay);
    }

    friend CArchive& operator>>(CArchive& rArchive, S_SPECIAL_EVENT &rsSE)
    {
        WORD wVersion{};

        rArchive >> wVersion;
        rsSE.bEventAllDay = readAndCast<BOOL, bool>(rArchive);

        return rArchive;
    }
};
```

I tried adding the two serialize operators. But I get compile errors like:

> error C3861: 'readAndCast': identifier not found

The method in question is defined in the application header:

```
// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58746336/2287576
template <typename T, typename U>
T readAndCast(CArchive& ar) {
    U x;
    ar >> x;
    return static_cast<T> (x);
}
```

I have included that header in my file. So why won't it complile?

---

I changed my code to do things manually:

```
friend CArchive& operator>>(CArchive& rArchive, S_SPECIAL_EVENT &rsSE)
{
    WORD wVersion{};
    bool bData{};

    rArchive >> wVersion;
    rArchive >> bData;
    rsSE.bEventAllDay = gsl::narrow<BOOL>(bData);

    return rArchive;
}
```

But I would like to know the answer to the original question.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal, reproducible example, that doesn't rely on numerous type and enum definitions that you have not provided?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Maybe there's an issue with the order of header includes? (Like the template not seeing the correct definition of `CArchive`?)

Comment: @AdrianMole OK, probably that then ...

Comment: @AdrianMole I think it is because the app class header file #includes the header file that defines the structure / operator. It is further down in the app header file that we define the readAndCast method.

Comment: Yep. That would cause the error you've cited.

Comment: @AdrianMole I could move the definition of readAndCast to before the header inclusion I guess but I don't like that idea.

Comment: Well, one way or another, you *have* to make sure that your definition of `readAndCast` is seen before you use it. If that's a function template that you use widely in your code, then it *should* be near the top of your 'global' header(s) and (long) before any specialisations of it are instantiated.

Comment: where did you add the #include ? If you add it before the stdafx.h or pch.h #include, then it won't be looked at. You need to include it after the precompiled header's #include.